# Is there a good alternative to individual try/catch statements?

Tags: java, try-catch

Code below is repetitive, no need to read all.

This code finds 8 neighbors around a plane, if the plane is on the edge
index can go out of bounds on each of them, hence I have to check each
individually

```
// Catch out of bound exception
try {
    // top
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index - rowLength));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Do nothing
}

try {
    // top left
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index - rowLength - 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Do nothing
}

try {
    // top right
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index - rowLength + 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Do nothing
}

try {
    // middle left
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index - 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Do nothing
}

try {
    // middle right
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index + 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Do nothing
}

try {
    // bottom
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index + rowLength));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
// Do nothing
}

try {
    // bottom left
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index + rowLength - 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
// Do nothing
}

try {
    // bottom right
    neighborPlanes.add((Plane) items.get(index + rowLength + 1));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
// Do nothing
}
```

Is there a way to make this not look terrible?
Would making a function call with nested try/catch inside be a better solution?

Comment: Yes, check you don't go out of bounds *before* trying to `get` from `items`. Don't use exceptions for flow control. An `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is something that should not happen in the first place.

Comment: Don't catch Runtime exceptions (because contrary to checked exceptions, runtime exceptions are not something that is somewhat expected to happen, but an indicator of a flaw in the code), and don't swallow exceptions by leaving catch blocks empty.

Comment: Okay, it seems people really don't like when I use try/catch like this, will make it the proper way, thanks for feedback, I always felt like this is a very comfortable way of doing this

Comment: *it seems people really don't like when I use try/catch like this* **Correct**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a separate method like `addNoThrow` that does the `add` with the same parameters inside a try/catch.

But as @federico-klez-culloca wrote, it's better to check the values first. That could be done in a `safeAdd` method that checks inputs and only gets and adds if they are valid.